# I have Ubuntu server 17.10 Running Plex and ram show all used

Tags: server, ram

I am new to Linux but google is my friend. I am having an issue with my amount of RAM. I have 10 GB of Ram on the machine and it hangs every I try to transfer data to my drive over the network. I checked my HTOP and Free which are giving odd amounts of RAM. I also have a 10 GB of Swap. Would someone please help with this as I love the Linux way better then windows.

**Update** During the transfer of data, about 10 files the Ubuntu errors out and must be restarted. It starts in safe mode and then I reboot again and it works for another 10 files.

Thank you for any help.

```
plex@Plex:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           9.8G        278M        172M        9.3M        9.3G        9.2G
Swap:           10G          0B         10G
```

plex@Plex:~$ clear
plex@Plex:~$ htop

```
 1  [                          0.0%]   Tasks: 46, 68 thr; 1 running
  2  [                          0.0%]   Load average: 0.00 0.01 0.00
  3  [                          0.0%]   Uptime: 01:49:28
  4  [                          0.0%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||288M/9.76G]
  Swp[                      0K/11.0G]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 1175 root       20   0 25284   292    60 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.17 /sbin/iscsid
  900 avahi      20   0 49332   356     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 avahi-daemon: chr
  951 plex       20   0  4608   620   544 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /bin/sh -c LD_LIB
  876 root       20   0 95472  1552  1416 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/lxcfs /v
  878 root       20   0 95472  1552  1416 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/lxcfs /v
  845 root       20   0 95472  1552  1416 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 /usr/bin/lxcfs /v
 1225 root       20   0 16116  1748  1608 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /sbin/agetty --no
  427 root       20   0  102M  2024  1796 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 /sbin/lvmetad -f
 1946 plex       20   0  114M  2176    40 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 (sd-pam)
  946 daemon     20   0 28256  2296  2084 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
  925 root       20   0 31236  2980  2696 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.02 /usr/sbin/cron -f
  856 root       20   0 38628  3460  3056 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.31 /usr/sbin/irqbala
  887 avahi      20   0 49460  3640  3232 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.12 avahi-daemon: run
  858 messagebu  20   0 47628  3764  3320 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.07 /usr/bin/dbus-dae
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4FilterF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit
```

Comment: Lets see some text rather than images!

Comment: What text would you like to see I put up pictures of both Htop and free information. I will provide you any details that may help.

Comment: Please copy and paste those texts into your OP!

Comment: Bros this won't cut it. Please edit your post and add them there!

Comment: I updated the main post

Comment: very little ram is actually used from what i see, it's just 'used' in buffering to increase performance which isn't technically used (as unallocated).  I suspect your understanding of what 'free' actually shows is wrong.  maybe try https://www.linuxnix.com/find-ram-size-in-linuxunix/

Comment: guiverc - The information from Free show total 9.8G and I am only using 295M then it shows only 139M free there should be 9G free.

Comment: wasted memory serves no purpose; hence the OS allows available memory to be used to aid performance. the moment an apps makes a malloc() (memory allocation request) it's given to the app as it was available. Whilst available, the system used it to store buffers read from disk hence in one count it was 'used', but in the other it was still 'available' as it hadn't been reserved.  The original unix spec was written in the 1970s where it was only seen by technical background people.  (also if the two different values weren't shown, we'd not be able to see how much was used in this way; the diff)